# properly handling 404 to make subsequent API call in subscribe method

Tags: kotlin, rx-android, subscribe

I am not an android developer, but I find myself supporting some android code.  I have a "doesExist" API call with a subscribe method on it.  If the API returns an error, I want a second API to be called, but inside the error callback for subscribe it doesn't make the call.  The function to make the request is called, but Charles shows me that the request is never actually made.  I've spent hours looking through blog posts and stackoverflow and haven't found an answer.

The code:

```
fun doesExistThenCreate(id: String) {
       remoteCase.doesCaseExist(id)
               .flatMap {
                   if (it) {
                       //some stuff
                   } else {
                       //create on 200 response but empty body
                       //this was the old way
                       remoteCase.createCase(id)
                   }
               }
               .subscribe({
                   //success actions
               }, { 
                   //doesExist returns 404, so call create.
                   //this is the new way, and it's not working
                   remoteCase.createCase(id)
               })
```

When the doesCaseExist API call is a success, a flatMap is applied, and part of the code in that block is to also call the second API.  This one always works when the doesExist returns a 200.

The original doesExist API used to return a 200 with an empty body if "it" didn't exist. When it doesn't exist, we want to create it.  We are changing the API to return a 404 when "it" doesn't exist, and we want to create it.  That's why you see two calls for create.  When this works properly, the one in flatMap will go away.

I've verified through a few Charles rewrites that it's the 404 response itself that's causing this to enter into the subscribe error callback.  When I debug, I can trace all the way down to the point of actually making the API call, but it doesn't.  It's like for some reason, it skips over actually making the second call when the first one throws a 404.

Obviously, what I want to have happen is that if doesCaseExist gets a 404, I want the createCase in the subsribe error callback to run.  I'm not sure if this is a threading issue, if I'm not handling the 404 properly, or if I just don't understand subscribe (all of which are completely possible).

Thanks for the help.  I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out that the problem. I didn't understand that the call to create in the subscribe was an observable that I never subscribes to.  Instead, I moved the call from the subscribe error callback to onErrorResumeNext so it can go through the chain and eventually get subscribed to.  I have no idea if this is the most correct way to do what I am trying to do, but it works.

```
   remoteCase.doesCaseExist(id)
           .flatMap {
               if (it) {
                   //some stuff
               } else {
                   //create on 200 response but empty body
                   //this was the old way
                   remoteCase.createCase(id)
               }
           }
           .onErrorResumeNext(
               remoteCase.createCase(id)
           )
           .subscribe({
               //success actions
           }, { 
               //error actions
           })
```